# android - programatically change listview background color

Tags: java, android

I created a custom listview and and created an adapter for it. I'd like to be able to programatically change different style aspects of different views within my custom listview. My custom listview is a RelativeLayout that has TextViews inside of it. i tried the following with no luck. No errors or anything.

```
View myView = adapter.getView(position, null, null);

myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#93E6CD"));       
myView.findViewById(R.id.layout).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#93E6CD"));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

here is my custom listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:id="@+id/layout">


    <!-- Title-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/primaryTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- Secondary title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondaryTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/primaryTitle"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:text="" />

    <!-- Rightend Data -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/primaryTitle"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:textColor="#B53021"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

We won't be able to proceed until you provide more information.

I suspect you're not setting up your ListView correctly. Are you really trying to display a list of similar items, such as rows from a database? If so, I would like to see the definition of the ListView object, either in code or in XML. I'd also like to see the definition of
adapter. That looks like you've defined a ListAdapter for the ListView, but I also want to know what is backing the ListAdapter.

The line

```
myView.findViewById(R.id.layout).setBackgroundColor()
```

looks suspicious. You seem to be looking for a child view of myView, but I don't see where you've defined this child view.

Usually, you define a ListView as part of your entire UI layout file, a separate item layout that defines one item in the ListView, and then adapt a data source to the ListView.

Comment: i think there are too many pieces to paste here. Let's say i wasn't using anything custom and had a basic list, when an item is clicked it starts an activity for result. I do so some things in the other activity and finish() out of that which brings me back to the list. How would i make the text green/background blue/whatever for that list item in the onActivityResult() method?